# What is the best imputation method for missing values in compositional data?

Tags: python, missing-data, data-imputation, censoring, compositional-data

I'm a little newbie at statistics, so I'm sorry if my question is too dumb.

I'm working with compositional datasets with several chemical elements (continuous data; arranged in columns), but also some categorical, multiclass data. My interest in my study is to run, test, and tune different classification algorithms using the chemical element data to predict the multi classes using python.

The most fundamental problem is that my dataset has some chemical elements (columns) with several "missing values" (it varies from 10% to > 65%). I quoted the missing values because they are presented as below some detection limit values (e.g., <10, <1, <150, etc.), therefore, they present valuable information that means that these values exist but are someplace between 0 and the detection limit. Also, for the same chemical element (e.g., potassium), there might be slightly different bdl values (e.g., in the same column, some data might be reported as <100, others as <120, <150, etc., but they kind of maintain a similar order of magnitude).

It is important to note that these types of data often don't follow a normal distribution, are right-skewed, commonly have outliers, and these outliers are important.

Is there any good imputation strategy where you don't need to assume a distribution to your data? Do you know of commonly used imputation methods for censored data in compositional data? If you could direct me to python libraries that deal with these imputations, it would be awesome!